# Counting distinct records across two tables

Tags: sql, count, distinct, ms-access-2003

Question concerning counting unique combination of fields across two tables in SQL.
MSaccess 2003.

```
table1: id, fld1, fld2
table2: id, dateAndTime
```

id is not unique; tables are joined across "id".

I need a count, by date (dd/mm/yy - ignoring time) of distinct combinations of `fld1` and `fld2` (int).

More specifically, I need to know which date has the most distinct combinations of `fld1` and `fld2`.

If table1 has

```
1, 101, 101
2, 101, 101
3, 101, 101
4, 101, 102
5, 101, 102
6, 101, 103
```

And table 2 has

```
1, 12/1/2010
2, 12/1/2010
3, 12/1/2010
1, 12/2/2010
2, 12/2/2010
4, 12/2/2010
5, 12/2/2010
6, 12/2/2010
```

I need

```
12/1/2010, 1     'only 1 unique combinatin of fld1 and fld2
12/2/2010, 3     'only 3 unique combinations of fld1 and fld2
```

But I only need "12/2/2010, 3" output as I just need the date and count of the largest count.

Couldn't figure out how to format this in the Commment to the correct answer below - so here it is for MS Access 2003.

```
Select TOP 5 theDay, count(*) AS theCount 
FROM ( 
Select cdate(int(date_col)) As theDay 
From tbl1 Inner Join tbl2 on tbl1.id=tbl2.id 
Group By cdate(int(date_col)), fld1, fld2 
) As X 
Group By theDay 
Order By 2 Desc;
```

This returns the TOP 5 combinations by Date (disregarding any time value)

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting to stackoverflow, but I have used it numerous times to find answers.
I have tried numerous things and get vague (to me) errors about agregate functions, etc. I am a very simple user of SQL and just know the basics about joining and selecting and where clauses.

Comment: Remember to supply your database system and version . Date / time handling differs a lot between flavors. *Edit* your question for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern RDBMS you can count distinct combinations in one go:

```
SELECT date_col, count(DISTINCT (fld1, fld2)) AS unique_combos
FROM   tbl1
JOIN   tbl2 USING (id)
GROUP  BY date_col;
```

Simpler method in two steps if that does not work:

```
SELECT date_col, count(*) AS unique_combos
FROM  (
   SELECT date_col
   FROM   tbl1
   JOIN   tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
   GROUP  BY date_col, fld1, fld2
   ) AS x
GROUP  BY date_col;
```

The second one should work in MS Access, too.

What @user2184214 finally went with:

```
SELECT TOP 5 theDay, count(*) AS theCount
FROM  (
   SELECT cdate(int(date_col)) AS theDay
   FROM   tbl1 
   JOIN   tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
   GROUP  BY cdate(int(date_col)), fld1, fld2
   ) AS x
GROUP  BY theDay
ORDER  BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: Ok - figured this out... thanks. It is so confusing.

Select TOP 5 theDay, count(*) AS theCount
FROM (
  Select cdate(int(date_col)) As theDay
  From tbl1 Inner Join tbl2 on tbl1.id=tbl2.id
  Group By cdate(int(date_col)), fld1, fld2
) As X
Group By theDay
Order By 2 Desc;

This returns the TOP 5 combinations by Date (disregarding any time value)

Comment: @user2184214: Cool! :) I added a formated version of your final solution to the answer. Maybe add `HAVING count(*) > 1` to weed out dates with a single combination? Consider deleting your earlier comments, which are superseded by your last.

Answer (score 0):

This query gives you what you want:

```
SELECT
  date(dateAndTime) AS date,
  count(DISTINCT (fld1, fld2)) AS count
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY 1
HAVING count(DISTINCT fld1, fld2) > 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: For MSAccess2003, this gives "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'count(Distinct fld1, fld2)'."